# Set Value to Enum - Java

Tags: java, android, enums

I'm trying to set values to enum in my java application....but I can't do that.

Am I doing it wrong???

```
public enum RPCPacketDataType {
    PT_UNKNOWN(2),
    PT_JSON(4),
    PT_BINARY(5)
};
```

It's giving me this error : The constructor RPCPacket.RPCPacketDataType(int) is undefined.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

```
public enum RPCPacketDataType
{
    PT_UNKNOWN(2),
    PT_JSON(4),
    PT_BINARY(5);

    RPCPacketDataType (int i)
    {
        this.type = i;
    }

    private int type;

    public int getNumericType()
    {
        return type;
    }
}
```

You can also define methods on your enum as you would in a "normal" class.

```
 System.out.println(RPCPacketDataType.PT_JSON.getNumericType() // => 4
```

Comment: I have another question. How can I do something like that:
RPCPacketDataType currentType;     if(currentType!=PT_JSON) return;

Comment: I'd use `switch` for enums: `switch (currentType) { case PT_JSON: ... }`

Comment: Actually I need only to check the PT_JSON,that's why I'm using if statement.But thanks for advance!

Answer (score 8):

You should create a Contructor which accepts an `int` parameter. Also add an `int` field which will hold the passed value.

```
public enum RPCPacketDataType {
    PT_UNKNOWN(2),
    PT_JSON(4),
    PT_BINARY(5);

    private int mValue;

    RPCPacketDataType(int value) {
        mValue = value;
    }
}
```

Comment: You may also want to add a getter to have access to the value later.

Comment: I hope one can easily add any method to this class oneself. The question is about adding values but not retrieving them :)

Answer (score 4):

```
public enum RPCPacketDataType { 

  PT_UNKNOWN(2), 
  PT_JSON(4),
  PT_BINARY(5); 

  private int type;

  RPCPacketDataType(int type) { 
    this.type = type; 
  }

  public int getNumericType() {
    return type;
  }

  public void setNumericType(int type) {
    this.type = type;
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    RPCPacketDataType.PT_UNKNOWN.setNumericType(0);
    System.out.println("Type: "+RPCPacketDataType.PT_UNKNOWN.getNumericType()); 
    // Type: 0
  }

}
```

As both #emboss and #Michael said correctly you can use a Contructor which accepts ant `int`